# unable to connect mongodb

Tags: mongodb

when i am trying to run 
'sudo service mongo start' then 
output is 'Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.'

the output of mongo is-:

```
x2@jj2:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.15
connecting to: test
2017-07-24T12:59:56.386+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2017-07-24T12:59:56.388+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

and status is :-

```
x2@jj2:~$ sudo service mongodb status
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-07-24 13:06:05 IST; 9min ag
  Process: 29210 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (co
 Main PID: 29210 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 24 13:06:05 x2 systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free docu
Jul 24 13:06:05 x2 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code
Jul 24 13:06:05 x2 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state
Jul 24 13:06:05 x2 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-
```

Comment: `mongo` ≠ `mongodb`. The latter service exists while the former doesn't according to the output of systemd. Did you try `sudo service mongodb start`?

Comment: yes i tried sudo service mongodb start

Comment: What's the output of that? Does it start the Mongo DB service? Could you please [edit] your question to clarify? Thanks.

Comment: this is the output:-'Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found'

Comment: You mistyped the service name *again*. It's supposed to **`mongodb`**, not `mongod` or `mongo`. Also, could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: this is the output of [sudo service mongodb start]--:{Job for mongodb.service failed because the control process exited with error code}.@ David Foerster

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-07-24 13:06:05 IST; 9min ag
```

**Failed** means not running thus you are getting:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017...
```

try running:

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```

Comment: I have tried this but still getting an error;  the error is:-                                   
 "Job for mongodb.service failed because the control process exited with error code."